# Hadoop: How to unit test FileSystem

Tags: unit-testing, hadoop

I want to run unit test but I need to have a org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem instance.
Are there any mock or any other solution for creating FileSystem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at the `hadoop-test` jar

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.20.205.0</version>
</dependency>
```

it has classes for setting up a `MiniDFSCluster` and `MiniMRCluster` so you can test without Hadoop

Answer (score 26):

If you're using hadoop 2.0.0 and above - consider using a hadoop-minicluster

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-minicluster</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

With it, you can create a temporary hdfs on your local machine, and run your tests on it. A setUp method may look like this:

```
baseDir = Files.createTempDirectory("test_hdfs").toFile().getAbsoluteFile();
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set(MiniDFSCluster.HDFS_MINIDFS_BASEDIR, baseDir.getAbsolutePath());
MiniDFSCluster.Builder builder = new MiniDFSCluster.Builder(conf);
hdfsCluster = builder.build();

String hdfsURI = "hdfs://localhost:"+ hdfsCluster.getNameNodePort() + "/";
DistributedFileSystem fileSystem = hdfsCluster.getFileSystem();
```

And in a tearDown method you should shut down your mini hdfs cluster, and remove temporary directory.

```
hdfsCluster.shutdown();
FileUtil.fullyDelete(baseDir);
```

Comment: That's integration testing.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use a mocking framework like Mockito or PowerMock to mock your interations with the FileSystem?  Your unit tests should not depend on an actual FileSystem, but should just be verifying behavior in your code in interacting with the FileSystem.

Comment: were you able to successfully mock `FileSystem`?

Answer (score 2):

One possible way would be to use **TemporaryFolder** in Junit 4.7.

See.: http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/07/junit-4.7-rules or http://weblogs.java.net/blog/johnsmart/archive/2009/09/29/working-temporary-files-junit-47.

Answer (score 1):

What I have done (until I will find better solution) I extended the FileSystem.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to create a ``` DummyFileSystem`` that extends abstract Hadoop ```FileSystem`, so I can fake if a file exists or not, etc. Example of "all file exists":

```
@Override
public FileStatus getFileStatus(Path f) throws IOException {
    return new FileStatus(10, false, 3, 128*1024*1024,1,1, null, null, null, f);
}
```

I found easier to keep control on faked data.

Answer (score 1):

I tried Thirupathi Chavati and Alexander Tokarev solutions with sbt, and :

`import org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster`

will only work by adding:

`libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-hdfs" % "2.8.1" classifier "tests"`
`libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "2.8.1" classifier "tests"`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at RawLocalFileSystem. Though I think you'd better just mock it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HBaseTestingUtility](https://hbase.apache.org/testapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseTestingUtility.html):

```
public class SomeTest {
    private HBaseTestingUtility testingUtil = new HBaseTestingUtility();

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        testingUtil.startMiniDFSCluster(1);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws IOException {
        testingUtil.shutdownMiniDFSCluster();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        DistributedFileSystem fs = testingUtil.getDFSCluster().getFileSystem();
        final Path dstPath = new Path("/your/path/file.txt);
        final Path srcPath = new Path(SomeTest.class.getResource("file.txt").toURI());
        fs.copyFromLocalFile(srcPath, dstPath);
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add below dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-minicluster</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
       <!-- <scope>test</scope>-->
    </dependency>
```

add the below code, it will create the FileSysetm.

```
import java.nio.file.{Files, Paths}


import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
import org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster


object MiniClusterDemo extends App {
  def sysDir: String = System.getProperty("user.dir")

  if(miniCluster!=null) println("Cluster created and active") else println("something went wrong")

  def miniCluster: FileSystem = {
    val basePath = Paths.get(s"$sysDir")

    val baseDir = Files.createTempDirectory(basePath,"hdfs_test").toFile.getAbsoluteFile
    val conf = new Configuration()
   conf.set(MiniDFSCluster.HDFS_MINIDFS_BASEDIR, baseDir.getAbsolutePath)
    val hdfsCluster = new MiniDFSCluster.Builder(conf).build()
    val hdfsURI = s"hdfs://localhost:${hdfsCluster.getNameNodePort}/"
    val fileSystem = hdfsCluster.getFileSystem
    //hdfsCluster.shutdown();
    //FileUtil.fullyDelete(baseDir);
    fileSystem
  }

}
```

See the sample logs after creation of MiniCluster

[image]